# How to specify retention period of join window?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to join two streams and I have set the join window to 25 hours as the records to be joined can be a maximum of 24 hours apart.

```
final Long JOIN_WINDOW = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(25);

kstream.join(
  runsheetIdStream,
  (jt,r) -> { jt.setDate(r.getStart_date()); return jt; },
  JoinWindows.of(JOIN_WINDOW),
  Joined.with(Serdes.Long(),jobTransactionSerde,runsheetSerde))
```

This is throwing the following exception:

> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: The retention period of the join window KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000016-store must be no smaller than its window size.

How do I increase the retention period?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `join` and used `JoinWindows.of(JOIN_WINDOW)` you implicitly defined the metadata of the underlying state store.

From the javadoc of [JoinWindows.of](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html#of-java.time.Duration-):

> Specifies that records of the same key are joinable if their timestamps are within timeDifference, i.e., the timestamp of a record from the secondary stream is max timeDifference earlier or later than the timestamp of the record from the primary stream.

The so-called **retention period** (aka *window maintain duration*) was earlier (before Kafka Streams 2.1.0) specified using [until](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/JoinWindows.html#until-long-):

> Set the window maintain duration (retention time) in milliseconds. This retention time is a guaranteed lower bound for how long a window will be maintained.

Since by default the retention is 1 day (can't find the reference at the moment) that's the reason for the exception.

As of Kafka Streams 2.1.0 you should be using [Materialized](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html) API:

> Used to describe how a StateStore should be materialized. You can either provide a custom StateStore backend through one of the provided methods accepting a supplier or use the default RocksDB backends by providing just a store name.

`Materialized` gives you a full control over the underlying state store for join and gives [withRetention(java.time.Duration retention)](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Materialized.html#withRetention-java.time.Duration-):

> Configure retention period for window and session stores.
>
> Note that the retention period must be at least long enough to contain the windowed data's entire life cycle, from window-start through window-end, and for the entire grace period.

Comment: I'm using Kafka Streams 2.4.0 and the API only accepts `JoinWindows`, am I missing something? did the API change again?

Comment: @SariAlalem That's possible. Haven't looked at it for some time.